# Не работает LiveData<> setValue?

Tags: android, mvvm, livedata

Пытаюсь писать приложение Андроид на MVVM. Создал ViewMode, Repository, MainActivty(View).
Но вот не работает метод LiveData setValue();

**ViewModel.java**

```
public class ListIssueViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<ApiResponse> mApiResponse;
    private IssueRepository mIssueRepository;

    public ListIssueViewModel(){
        mApiResponse = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        mIssueRepository = new IssueRepositoryImpl();
    }

    public LiveData<ApiResponse> getApiResponse(){
        return mApiResponse;
    }

    public void loadIssues(String user, String repo){
        ApiResponse response = mIssueRepository.getIssues(user, repo).getValue();
        mApiResponse.setValue(response);
    }
}
```

В методе `loadData()` идет запрос к репозиторию и он грузит данные.  Но вот setValue почему то не устанавливает данные в MutableLiveData. И наверно поэтому ошибка ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListIssueViewModel.class);
    //Тут ошибка вылетает
    //Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.xllnc.mvvmexample.entity.ApiResponse.getIssues()' on a null object reference
mViewModel.getApiResponse().observe(this, apiResponse -> mAdapter.addIssues(apiResponse.getIssues()));
mViewModel.loadIssues("square", "retrofit");
```

Вот, если надо код Репозитория.
**IssueRepository.java**

```
public class IssueRepositoryImpl implements IssueRepository {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
    private GitHubApiService mApiService;

    public IssueRepositoryImpl(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();
        mApiService = retrofit.create(GitHubApiService.class);
    }

public LiveData<ApiResponse> getIssues(String owner, String repo) {
        final MutableLiveData<ApiResponse> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Call<List<Issue>> call = mApiService.getIssues(owner, repo);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Issue>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Issue>> call, Response<List<Issue>> response) {
                liveData.setValue(new ApiResponse(response.body()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Issue>> call, Throwable t) {
                liveData.setValue(new ApiResponse(t));
            }
        });
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call.enqueue(...)` в `getIssues()` выполняется асинхронно, поэтому return возвращает лайвдату без значения и getValue() в `loadIssues` возвращает null и в `mApiResponse.setValue()` идёт null, а т.к. в адаптер тоже идёт null, то ничего не происходит. Сделайте mApiResponse MediatorLiveData и вместо

```
ApiResponse response = mIssueRepository.getIssues(user, repo).getValue();
mApiResponse.setValue(response);
```

используйте это

```
LiveData<ApiResponse> source = mIssueRepository.getIssues(user, repo);
mApiResponse.addResource(source, apiResponse -> {
    mApiResponse.setValue(apiResponse);
    mApiResponse.removeSource(source);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, ждал такого объяснения весь день

Answer (score 0):

Он и не будет работать, вам нужен метод: [`postValue()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#postValue(T)), а `setValue()` используется для установления значения в `mainThread`, вы же выполнеете свою задачу асинхронно, соответственно коллбек увас срабатывает в инном потоке.

Comment: А почему в Repository, метод onResponse() устанавливает через setValue, а не postValue ?

Comment: Колбеки onResponse и onFailure выполняются на основном потоке

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon А если сделать вот так, `ApiResponse value = mIssueRepository.getIssues(user, repo).getValue();
        mApiResponse.postValue(value);` То тут первая строчка выполняется асинхронно ? А вторая ждет пока она не выполнится ?? или как ?